# My webserver won't register css file changes

Tags: php, html, css, xampp

At first, when I saw in the Chrome Developer console that my CSS file was not updating, I thought it was a problem with my text editor. So I switched from VSCode to Sublime 3 and encountered the same error. It had updated slightly, but not much. So after a while I swithced again to Atom, and still encountered the same problem. I even switched my Webserver from MAMP for Windows to XAMPP. Still no dice. When I say updating, I mean the file would save, but the changes wouldn't appear in my browser.

Comment: what are you using as a server? e.g. apache on your local machine, nginx on a  remote managed host, etc

Comment: You can blame caching.

Comment: are you doing a "hard refresh"? If you simply refresh the page, the browser may be using a cached version of some assets.

Comment: This is cache related. To fix it, add a version number behind your .css url. Like so: <link rel="stylesheet" href="my-css.css?v=1">

Comment: @Gerard Yes but then that would also keep caching `v` as `1` Best to use a timed method.

Comment: @danyamachine I am using XAMPP to locally host apache

Answer (score -3, accepted):

This is the issue with browser caching, and clearing it every time you update your CSS isn't a viable solution.

You can either go the short route and open your website in **incognito mode**. This will clear cache each time you revisit the page.

I recommend you disable caching for your website while working on it. I assue you're running **Apache** on your server, and then it's simply a matter of including this tag in your `.htaccess` file.

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Cache-Control "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
    Header set Pragma "no-cache"
    Header set Expires 0
</IfModule>
```

or this snippet in your HTML `<head>`

```
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" />
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />
```

Follow these instruction for a more in-depth implementation [How to control web page caching, across all browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49547/how-to-control-web-page-caching-across-all-browsers#answers)

Comment: Oh and do that every time? Not a good solution.

Comment: just change the browser